# how to use asp.net cache on windows azure with multiple instances

Tags: asp.net, caching, azure, cloud

hey guys if i have an azure web app running under multiple instances how do i use asp.net cache. has the azure team written any cache providers for azure?

i read somewhere they are going to support velocity in future but if i have to go live with some app in next couple of months what is the best way i can cache my data (i dont want to use sql server cache as that simply defeats my purpose of caching in the first place)

Comment: I did have a look at the problem, and I am not aware of anything but the velocity project.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few options now -

1) Check out azuresqlsession.codeplex.com - a custom session provider that works with SQL Azure.  It's much faster than the custom provider Microsoft wrote that works with azure table storage.

2) There's also "AppFabric Caching" - a distributed cache that runs in the azure data centers.  Microsoft also wrote a custom session provider that works with AppFabric Caching.  Currently it's in CTP and you can get it here - portal.appfabriclabs.com - there's a good overview on how to use it here - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazureappfabric/archive/2010/10/28/introduction-to-windows-azure-appfabric-caching-ctp.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0 - and also in the azure sdk 1.3 labs.

I realize the question was asked a while back - I just thought I'd update it if someone stumbled upon the question after a google/bing search.

Good times!
about.me/ehuna

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to update with latest Info as I just stumbled upon this post:

Windows Azure Cache is live and running in full Swing, learn more here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg278356.aspx

Here is an example to show how to use Windows Azure Cache with ASP.NET application:

1. How To: Add and Retrieve an Object from the Cache
2. How To: Specify the Expiration of an Object in the Cache
3. How To: Store ASP.NET Session State in the Cache
4. How To: Store ASP.NET Page Output Caching in the Cache

https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/cache/

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft plans to implement a [Windows Azure Cache Provider](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazure/thread/467109ce-9c3f-44eb-bb27-1ebf05e5157d) when ASP.NET Cache extensibility ships with .NET 4.0.

In the meantime, could you cache separately on each instance and then maybe use queue storage to message between instances for cache invalidation?